# React Native Post Error 'Cannot Load Empty URL'

Tags: post, react-native

Trying to make a POST request in React using code below.  To maintain privacy I've deleted the actual parameters and inserted fake ones for the url, accesskey and varArgs variables.  When I try to kick off the request I am getting - 'Error: Cannot load an empty url'. My url variable is a valid string and the post request works fine from curl.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Picker
} from 'react-native';

var vsprintf = require('sprintf-js').vsprintf

class plantMetrics extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    const url = 'http://myurl.com'
    const accessKey = 'myaccesskey'
    const varArgs = '{"arg1":"val1"}'

    this.state = {
      catalogMeta: 'shit',
      workspace: '',
      measure: '',
      bu: '',
      country: '',
      plant: '',
      region: ''
    }
  }
    getCatalogInfo(){
    fetch(this.url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',  
        'Authorization': this.accessKey
      },
      body: this.varArgs
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({catalogMeta: JSON.stringify(responseJson.body)})
    })
    .catch((error) => {      
      this.setState({catalogMeta: 'error: ' + error})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{"\n"}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.catalogMeta}</Text>
         <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.getCatalogInfo.bind(this)}>
            <Text>Fetch</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables below

```
const url = 'http://myurl.com'
const accessKey = 'myaccesskey'
const varArgs = '{"arg1":"val1"}'
```

are only in scope in the `constructor` method. To make them accessible via `this`, set them using `this`:

```
this.url = 'http://myurl.com'
this.accessKey = 'myaccesskey'
this.varArgs = '{"arg1":"val1"}'
```

Comment: Is there a solution when using react hooks instead of classes?

Comment: I am not using any variables instead I am passing urls and keys directly into the function but still getting the same warning any idea about that